# Is there an `edefault` in the spirit of `gdefault` for setting the appropriate flags in vim's substitution commands?

Tags: vimrc, substitute, options, default-settings

To perform a buffer-wide substitution on all occurrences of `foo` (and not just the 1st one in a line), we can do

> %s/foo/bar/g

The `g` flag may be omitted by setting this in the `vimrc` as

> set gdefault

If the pattern `foo` is not found, `vim` raises an error

> E486: Pattern not found: foo

This error can be avoided by specifying the `e` flag to the substitution operator i.e.

> %s/foo/bar/ge

My question is, can an equivalent option (say `edefault`) that can be put together in a `vimrc` to achieve this effect?

Comment: No, there is not and btw: I would not recommend setting `gdefault`. It is to obscure and I suspect too many plugins cannot handle it

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Ok, I agree with your views on `gdefault`. What about `edefault`. Can something be cooked up?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with `cooked up`. In interactive mode, a missing `edefault` does not make sense since the error message is quite helpful. Scripts/plugins however can use various ways to compensate, using either `try/catch` or always including the `e` flag. So what exact problem are you trying to solve here?